# Why can't I include a column from another table in my results?

Tags: sql, group-by

**UPDATE: After spending some time on this, I have realised that the best way to describe this problem concisely is to say that I am looking for the equivalent of a `VLOOKUP` in SQL (albeit using grouped values).**

I have a query which joins two tables on surrogate key fields (`specialty` and `specialty_sk`).

I want to count the total number of unique values under `specialty` which I do like so:

```
SELECT specialty_sk, COUNT(*)
FROM [Appointment_vw]
WHERE [appointment date] BETWEEN '2021-02-01' AND '2021-02-07'
GROUP BY specialty_sk
```

This works as expected:

[image]

However, when I join to the surrogate key field in another table in order to pull the name for each specialty in, I receive this:

```
Column 'Specialty_vw.specialty' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Query:

```
SELECT A.specialty_sk, S.specialty
FROM [Appointment_vw] A INNER JOIN [Specialty_vw] S
ON A.specialty_sk = S.specialty
WHERE [appointment date] BETWEEN '2021-02-01' AND '2021-02-07'
GROUP BY A.specialty_sk
```

Or

```
SELECT A.specialty_sk, COUNT(*), S.specialty
FROM [Appointment_vw] A INNER JOIN [Specialty_vw] S
ON A.specialty_sk = S.specialty
WHERE [appointment date] BETWEEN '2021-02-01' AND '2021-02-07'
GROUP BY A.specialty_sk
```

Or

```
SELECT A.specialty_sk, COUNT(specialty_sk), S.specialty
FROM [Appointment_vw] A INNER JOIN [Specialty_vw] S
ON A.specialty_sk = S.specialty
WHERE [appointment date] BETWEEN '2021-02-01' AND '2021-02-07'
GROUP BY A.specialty_sk
```

In other versions of the above queries, I have received messages regarding some variables not being able to be cast from `varchar` to `int`.

Where am I going wrong here?  I assume that it has something to do with `COUNT(*)`.

If so, then how can I find out what each `specialty` code is without pulling in the `specialty_sk` field from the other table? (The `[Appointment_vw]` table is almost 32,000,000 rows deep so this wouldn't be ideal.)

What I want to achieve is a count of all of the unique `specialty` values from `A` and then to pull in the names of those specialties from `S` and display them alongside the results shown above in a new column.

I can only assume it's to do with the fact that I am grouping my results, whereas on the `JOIN` I am looking to pull in a single value that identifies the `specialty` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time spent trying to work this out, I discovered where I had gone wrong - I had overlooked selecting the field that I was trying to pull in (`S.specialty`).

The correct query is:

```
SELECT A.specialty_sk, S.specialty, COUNT(A.specialty_sk)
FROM Appointment_vw A INNER JOIN Specialty_vw S
ON A.specialty_sk = S.Specialty_sk
WHERE CAST([appointment date] AS DATE) BETWEEN '2021-02-01' AND '2021-02-07'
GROUP BY A.specialty_sk, S.Specialty
```

As such, instead of getting this:

```
specialty_sk    n
spec1           34
spec2           3
spec3           87
```

I now get this:

```
specialty_sk    specialty                 n
spec1           specialty number one      34
spec2           specialty number two      3
spec3           specialty number three    87
```

Thank you everyone for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a `GROUP BY`, any column that you have in the `SELECT` which is not being aggregated/counted etc needs to also be in the `GROUP BY`. So the following *should* produce the results you are expecting if there is a 1-1 mapping between on `A.specialty_sk = S.specialty`

```sql
SELECT
    A.specialty_sk,
    COUNT(*),
    S.specialty
FROM [Appointment_vw] A INNER JOIN [Specialty_vw] S
ON A.specialty_sk = S.specialty
WHERE [appointment date] BETWEEN '2021-02-01' AND '2021-02-07'
GROUP BY A.specialty_sk, S.specialty
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but this brings me back to the other errors that I alluded to (conversion errors): `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '142 Category 1' to data type int.` Why might this be happening (or, how can I fix this)?

Comment: Seems like your join `A.specialty_sk = S.specialty` is joining on two different datatypes. Are you sure that these columns are the right ones to join on? Normally a surrogate key is an INT that will join to another surrogate key which is also an INT.

Comment: That makes sense and perhaps that is the issue; in that case, assuming that it is a type-for-type join, how can I pull in the column of names that correspond with each code and display those alongside the results from my first query (image above)?

Comment: Assuming that the name column you're looking for is in the `Specialty_vw table`... you need to make sure that there is a column in the `Specialty_vw` table that can actually join back to the `Appointment_vw` table. If you find that you can in fact join on the `Specialty_vw.speciality` column then you could use a sql-server `try_cast`. which would look something like `A.specialty_sk = try_cast(S.specialty as int)`. Instead of throwing an error, it will not join on that row which it cannot cast to an int

Comment: Unfortunately that only produces `NULL`s. Perhaps I haven't worded my question correctly. Both `A` and `S` are joined on `specialty_sk`. The value I am looking to pull in and show alongside the original results is `specialty`, where the name of the specialty is listed so that I can show how many of each specialty exists within the dataset.